# How do I access attributes of the join model in a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Using the example on [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association):

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

Say `Appointment` has the attribute `exam_room_id`. I want to use ActiveRecord to obtain a result set that contains a `Physician's` `Patients` and what exam room the `Patient` is in.

I feel like I should be able to do something like this:

```
Physician.first.patients.each do |patient|
  patient.appointment.exam_room_id    
end
```

This does not work because a `Physician has_many :appointments` (i.e.: not a single appointment).

Is there an elegant 'rails way' of accessing the attributes of `Appointment` together with either side of the `has_many :through?`

Comment: Do you need the resultset to return exam_room_id for all the appointments?

Comment: I would think you would actually have to ask for ``patient.appointment.first.exam_room_id``

Comment: rrb: Ideally the result set would have one record for each combination of `Physician`, `Appointment` and `Patient` -- as though the query was written against the appointment table, and it was grabbing the physician and patient data also.  I realize that I can solve the problem using custom sql or even ActiveRecord tables -- I was hoping there was a nice "rails way" of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to step through each appointment.

```
Physician.first.patients.each do |patient|
  patient.appointments.each {|appointment| puts appointment.exam_room_id}
end
```

This would show you every exam room a patient has ever been in (based on their appointments). I don't think is exactly what you're looking for but wanted to illustrate you need to iterate over each physician or patient appointment to get the room_id.

If you're wanting a result set of current rooms you're going to want to go through the appointments. `Physician.first.appointments.each`. Also, how are you distinguishing between current and past appointments?

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following because appointments table is included in the join query implicitly,

```
Physician.first.patients.select("appointments.exam_room_id ")
   .each{|patient| patient.exam_root_id}
```